# How to give JFrame antialiased rounded corners?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, rounded-corners, antialiasing

Good day!
So I like the idea of having rounded corners. So I added them. But there's quite a big catch! The corners look pretty terrible. They bring a new definition to 'jagged'. That's why I'm here! I just couldn't find anyone who had the same problem.

Code I used: `frame.setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 500, 325, 20, 20));`

My problem is that I can't figure out how to antialias the rounded corners of a JFrame. You can do it with images, but that's different. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
-Me

Comment: The code that paints a JFrame (Window) is native system code.  You can try larger circles (50, 50) or (100 100).